# Move around the characters in a filename

Tags: regex, bash

I've got a folder full of files with the names ab1234, abc5678, etc., and I want to switch them to abc3412, abc7856, etc. – just swap the last two characters out with the second-to-last two characters. The filenames are all in this format, no surprises. What's the easiest way to do this with a regex?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your platform, you may have a `rename` utility that can directly do what you want.
For instance, [anishsane's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34348298/45375) shows an elegant option using a Perl-based renaming utility.

Here's a **POSIX-compliant** way to do it:

```
printf '"%s"\n' * | sed 'p; s/\(..\)\(..\)"$/\2\1"/' | xargs -L 2 mv
```

- `printf '"%s"\n' *` prints all files in the current folder line by line (if there are subdirs., you'd have to exclude them), enclosed in literal double-quotes.
- `sed 'p; s/\(..\)\(..\)"$/\2\1"/'` produces 2 output lines:

  - `p` prints the input line as-is.
  - `s/\(..\)\(..\)"$/\2\1"/'` matches the last 2 character pairs (before the closing `"`) on the input lines and swaps them.
  - The net effect is that each input line produces a *pair* of output lines: the original filename, and the target filename, each enclosed in double-quotes.
- `xargs -L 2 mv` then reads pairs of input lines (`-L 2`) and invokes the `mv` utility with each line as its own argument, which results in the desired renaming. Having each line enclosed in double-quotes ensures that `xargs` treats them as a *single* argument, even if they should contain whitespace.

<sup>Tip of the hat to [anishsane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793796/anishsane) for the enclose-in-literal-double-quotes approach, which makes the solution robust.</sup>

Note: If you're willing to use non-POSIX features, you can simplify the command as follows, to bypass the need for extra quoting:

- GNU `xargs`:

  ```
  printf '%s\n' * | sed 'p; s/\(..\)\(..\)$/\2\1/' | xargs -d '\n' -L 2 mv
  ```

  Nonstandard option `-d '\n'` tells `xargs` to not perform word splitting on lines and treat each line as a single argument.
- BSD `xargs` (also works with GNU `xargs`):

  ```
  printf '%s\n' * | sed 'p; s/\(..\)\(..\)$/\2\1/' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -L 2 mv
  ```

  `tr '\n' '\0'` replaces newlines with `\0` (NUL) chars, which is then specified as the input-line separator char. for `xargs` with the nonstandard `-0` option, again ensuring that each input line is treated as a single argument.

Comment: I would suggest `printf '"%s"\n' * | sed 'p; s/\(..\)\(..\)"$/\2\1"/'`, to take care of the filenames with spaces (spaces being the most common IFS characters in filenames).

Comment: @anishsane: Excellent point, thank you. I've incorporated your suggestion into the answer, and I've also added non-POSIX alternatives that obviate the need for embedded quoting.

Comment: In GNU xargs case: `xargs -d '\n' -L 2 de` what is `de`? That utulity is not available on ubuntu I think... Or is it a typo?

Comment: @anishsane: My bad: it was a testing artifact; it was supposed to be `mv` - fixed now. (`de` is a custom debug utility whose name stands for *d*ebug *e*cho, and whose purpose is to show argument boundaries.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`perl rename`](http://man.cx/prename)?

```
rename 's/(..)(..)$/$2$1/' *
```